# Python/Keras - accessing ModelCheckpoint callback

Tags: python, keras

I'm using Keras to predict a time series. As standard I'm using 20 epochs. I want to know what did my neural network predict for each one of the 20 epochs.

By using model.predict I get the last prediction. However I want all predictions, or at least the last 10 ones (which have acceptable error levels).

To access that I'm trying the ModelCheckpoint function from Keras, however I'm having trouble to access it afterwards. I'm using the following code:

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(GRU(input_dim=col,init='uniform',output_dim=20))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer="RMSprop")

checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/Users/Alex/checkpoint.hdf5')

model.fit(X=predictor_train, y=target_train, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=batch,validation_split=0.1) #best validation split at 0.1
model.evaluate(X=predictor_train, y=target_train,batch_size=batch,show_accuracy=True)

print checkpoint
```

Objectively, my questions are:

- I expected that after running the code I would find a file named checkpoint.hdf5 inside the folder /Users/Alex, however I didn't. What am I missing?
- When I print `checkpoint` out what I get is a `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint object at 0x117471290`. Is there a way to print what I want? How would the code look like?

Your help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems in this code:

- You are not passing the callback to the model's fit method. This is done with the keyword argument "callbacks".
- The filepath should contain placeholders (like "{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}" that are used with str.format by Keras in order to save each epoch to a different file.

So the correct version should be something like:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/Users/Alex/checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5')

model.fit(X=predictor_train, y=target_train, nb_epoch=20,
         batch_size=batch,validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

You can also add other kinds of callbacks in the list that is assigned to that keyword.

Unfortunately the callback object doesn't store the history information so it cannot be recovered from it.

Comment: Is there a way to have that file in csv or txt? hdf5 is quite difficult to work with...

Comment: @abutremutante No, and HDF5 is pretty easy to use with h5py, but why do you need to work with it? You can load the weights to your model with load_weights

Comment: is it possible to pass custom parameter to filepath?
How it is: `ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}-{val_loss:.3f}.hdf5'`
How I want to be:
`ModelCheckpoint('model-{}-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}-{val_loss:.3f}.hdf5'.format(model_name)`